# nmap shows 8080/tcp open http-proxy on centos 7 VPS but lsof shows nothing for that port

Tags: iptables, linode, nmap, http-proxy

Im running a Centos 7 VPS server for the past several years.  Originally when
I set it up I didnt install any firewall (`iptables` specifically) because I was
under the impression the host (`linode`) needed them open to admin the box from
their side.  Yes I know, really dumb mistake.  Other things like `ssh`, `apache` etc
I locked down and hardened well along with using `fail2ban` and I keep things patched on a daily basis where required.

At this point I believe Im likely hacked after closing things up via
`iptables` and locking things down. It's a `LAMP` box.  I have no proof at this point just suspicion.  Im the only user and things are working fine.

When I run `nmap` against the server now I have everything locked down the way I want
it except I see the following open even though `iptables` should be blocking 8080 via a DROP:

```
sudo nmap -sS -O -p8080 x.x.x.x

Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-06-09 19:52 MST
Nmap scan report for mydomain.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.018s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 2.6.32 (94%), Linux 2.6.32 or 3.10 (94%), Linux 2.6.35 (94%), Linux 3.5 (94%), Linux 4.2 (94%), Tandberg VCS video conferencing system (94%), Synology DiskStation Manager 5.1 (94%), Linux 2.6.39 (92%), Linux 3.10 (92%), Linux 3.10 - 3.12 (92%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
```

Running `lsof` and doesnt show me anything on port 8080 however I do see
some `rpcbind` listed and am unsure if any of these could be related?

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rpcbind   451    rpc    6u  IPv4  25873      0t0  UDP *:sunrpc 
rpcbind   451    rpc    7u  IPv4  25922      0t0  UDP *:compaq-evm 
rpcbind   451    rpc    8u  IPv4  25923      0t0  TCP *:sunrpc (LISTEN)
rpcbind   451    rpc    9u  IPv6  25924      0t0  UDP *:sunrpc 
rpcbind   451    rpc   10u  IPv6  25925      0t0  UDP *:compaq-evm 
rpcbind   451    rpc   11u  IPv6  25926      0t0  TCP *:sunrpc (LISTEN)
```

From the outside I can `telnet x.x.x.x 8080` and it responds, however trying to use
a common `GET HTTP/1.1` command doesnt reply at all and it times out after a minute or so.

When I `telnet` in on port 8080, I run `lsof | grep http` and I see the following:

```
lsof | grep http
NetworkMa   514          root  mem       REG                8,0    162144       5038 /usr/lib64/libnghttp2.so.14.17.0
gmain       514   517    root  mem       REG                8,0    162144       5038 /usr/lib64/libnghttp2.so.14.17.0
gdbus       514   519    root  mem       REG                8,0    162144       5038 /usr/lib64/libnghttp2.so.14.17.0
```

I dont run `nghttp2` so Im guessing that it part of `Linode` admin package they preinstalled?

Any ideas on how to find this process and kill it?
A bonus would be understanding what it is as well but Id be happy just to get
rid of it.

Thank you for any advice or pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: This is a little helpful, though much of it I already know.  I'll have to re-install for sure but would like to learn forensically from this mistake and understand it better and hopefully plug this particular hole until I can find time to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

looks like `lsof` doesn't show sockets owned by user who created that 8080 binding.
From this output it says NetworkMa[nager?] with pid=514 (if I got it correctly without header)

```
lsof | grep http
NetworkMa   514 ...
```

Does this service restart automatically? `pstree` can show a chain with that process (probably it can clarify a bit)
p.s. cannot put it in comments, so just added in answers

Comment: Yes, NetworkManager starts automatically.  I didnt set it up, it came installed on the machine.  I looked at pstree and didnt see anything that stuck out as being the process thats causing this.  I know Ill have to re-install the machine at some point I just dont have several days to do so at this point, so plugging the hole is my best choice ATM (realizing that there might be others I dont know about).

Comment: yes, maybe it's the right choice to be sure

Comment: another one suggestion to get some extra info if that NetworkManager is problematic: compare checksums of the local /usr/sbin/NetworkManager and its original binary (extracting this file from .deb package of the same version)